# add new entry at the bottom of table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table Name(Column1,Column2,Column3,) values('" @+value1+,@+value2+,@+value3+ "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

above code is simple format of my db query,when i try to insert record into db the record went to at the top of table instead of bottom,i want to save new entry at bottom not top or middle.

Comment: it depends on your primary key where you have mentioned .

Comment: And is there any reason why it need to be at bottom?

Comment: no i don't have any primary key

Comment: @ShivvanandPatil Do you have clustered index? If yes, what's its definition?

Comment: reason is when i fetch data from table i want only specific rows which already there at top,i dont want to add new entry between specific row

Comment: no there is nothing in indexes folder @gotqn

Comment: Tables are *unordered* collections of rows. There is no "top" or "bottom". The only thing that provides any ordering *guarantees* are an `ORDER BY` clause applied to any particular `SELECT` query that is retrieving rows.

Comment: this is not a good option for me,,

Comment: That's like saying that gravity isn't a good option for you. It's not something thats optional. It's the reality you're working with. Or, to put it another way, your options here are a) to make sure you're storing sufficient information in one or more columns such that you'll be able to apply the `ORDER BY` you want during retrieval or b) to move to some other storage technology for your data. In SQL, tables are unordered.

Comment: @ShivvanandPatil What's the real issue here? Why you are worried about how rows are physically materialized?

Comment: If you don't have clustered primary key in table then data save as heap without any order. And in this case each SELECT-query can return the result in a different order. I recomend to add a surrogate primary key  to your table (for example ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED). After that your data will order by this order automaticaly or you can order it how you want (ORDER BY ID or ORDER BY ID DESC). I think this surrogate column will be very useful.

Comment: @SergeyMenshov - please stop perpetuating the *myth* that the clustered index provides *any* kind of ordering guarantees.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Ok. I wanted to say in any case an additional column will be useful for order his data how he want.

Comment: As they said Patil, SQL stores records in the order it sees fit. When reading records, it reads them as it sees fit. There isn't any *guaranteed default* order, since there isn't some *imposed* metadata like MS Excel's row numbers to the side. Your only *guaranteed* option is `ORDER BY`, so either you're lucky something in your data can indicate the order (*e.g. some timestamp*), or you add a column for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server or any SQL database whenever you insert a new record, it is being inserted at the end or the end of the table. If What you are expecting by inserting the record at the beginning is to get the record as the first one while retrieving the same, then you can try ordering them in the descending order - Which is recommended.

Another way of achieving the same is if you have a sequence column in the table then insert the new record with the sequence as the current minimum sequence -1. Something like this.

Create the table with the Sequence column as decrement by 1

```
create table MyTable
(
    SeqNo int identity(1000,-1),
    Data1 VARCHAR(50)
)
```

As per the above design, the first record begin inserted into the table will have the SeqNo 1000 and for each record being inserted next will have SeqNo decremented by 1. Like the 2nd one will have SeqNo 999, 3rd one 998 and so on.

> But What I recommend is you go with the order by Desc approach if all
>   you need is to get the latest record first on your search

Comment: i got it,,thnx to all, i just add one column with identity specification..also this will work but i m happy with it...